# The solution set of the equation $|\lfloor x|x|-7\rfloor|<5$ is?

Tags: inequality, contest-math, absolute-value, ceiling-and-floor-functions

My solution approach :-
$|\lfloor x|x|-7\rfloor|<5$
When $x\geq 0$, then;
$|\lfloor x^2-7\rfloor|<5$
$\Rightarrow -5 \lt \lfloor x^2-7\rfloor \lt5$

After this I do know that I'll have to take another case in which $x\lt0$ but I am not able to get how to solve the floor function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far, when $x\geq 0$ you got here
$$
-5 \lt \lfloor x^2-7\rfloor \lt5
$$
This means $\lfloor x^2-7\rfloor \in \{-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4\}$ or in other words $x^2 - 7 \in [-4,5)$.
Therefore we have
$$
x^2 \in [3,12),
$$
or
$$
x\in[\sqrt{3},2\sqrt{3}).
$$
Note that $x\in(-2\sqrt{3}, -\sqrt{3}]$ is excluded because we only take $x\geq 0$.

For the case $x\leq 0$, we have
$$
-5 < \lfloor -x^2 - 7 \rfloor < 5.
$$
But $\lfloor -x^2 - 7 \rfloor \leq -7 < -5$, therefore there are no solutions for the case $x\leq 0$.

To sum it all up, the solution set of the equation $|\lfloor x|x|-7\rfloor|<5$ is $x\in[\sqrt{3},2\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: [+1] for the solution ;  but saying "I don't see what the problem is." is not good. If the OP ask for it, it is because there is a gap in his/her techniques for solving the problem : it is very understandable...

Comment: @JeanMarie I understand, and I have removed that sentence. However, just saying "I am not able to solve this" shows a lack of trying in my book, and the author of the question did not specify where the particular problem was, what he tried, and why he was not able to finish the problem. With that in mind, and given that the problem was not overly complicated, and also that the harder part (in my opinion) of the problem was already solved, I believe that my comment was on par with the question.

Comment: Sorry for this late question, in this line"This means $\lfloor x^2-7\rfloor \in \{-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4\}$ or in other words $x^2 - 7 \in [-4,5)$.", why haven't you written $[-4,4]$?

Comment: Because if $x^2 -7\in (4,5)$ then we still have $\lfloor x^2-7\rfloor =4$.

Comment: Lemme put down my doubt more lucidly :- In the first case when you have taken $x \geq 0$ then that means $-5 \lt \lfloor x^2-7\rfloor \lt5$ and this will give that $\lfloor x^2-7\rfloor$ will have the solution set as ${-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}$ but you have after this written that $x^2 - 7 \in [-4,5)$ and I was wondering why can't we write $x^2 - 7 \in [-4,4]$ and this will give the solution as $\sqrt{3} \leq x \leq \sqrt{11}$. Is this wrong?

Comment: By the definition of the floor function we have $\lfloor y \rfloor = a$ if and only if $y\in [a,a+1)$. By extending this to $a\in\{-4,-3,\ldots,3,4\}$ we obtain $[-4,5)$.